# Можно ли как-то узнать какие опции уже установлены пременной с cURL десприптором?

Tags: curl

Можно ли как-то узнать какие опции уже установлены пременной с cURL десприптором?

Comment: А вот если я залогинился. Получил нужyные данные в частности ссылку, мне нужно её вызвать чтобы произошел гет запрос, нужно закрыть предидущий дескриптор и создать новый, использовать этот же просто изменить URL? Что делать в данной ситуации, подскажите пожалуйста? Ну то есть просто получается я же получил cookie то есть авторизировался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [аналогичном вопросе на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356075/how-to-get-an-option-previously-set-with-curl-setopt) говорят, что нет, и cоветуют обёртывать дескриптор в класс, который будет сохранять опции при установке.

Answer (score 2):

Есть функция [curl_getinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php). Но это не совсем то, что вы хотите. Просто взять и получить список установленных опций из дескриптора, **МНЕ КАЖЕТСЯ**, невозможно.

Comment: про эту функцию знаю но она не подходит. Тогда еще вопрос. А после curl_exec опции дескриптора слетают или нет?

Comment: @jeremen1, нет не слетают до тех пор пока Вы не выполните curl_close()